Eliminating results based on certain criteria
I have a table with periods and values
I am trying to eliminate all pre-0  results when a 0 occurs in the table. I tried to apply some filters but failed
    WITH PERIODS AS 
 (
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   1 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   2 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   3 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   4 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   5 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   0 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   6 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   7 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   8 value FROM dual UNION
 SELECT    TO_DATE('2020-01-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  PERIOD,   9 value FROM dual 

 )        
 select * from PERIODS

 full result set
 01-JAN-20  1
 02-JAN-20  2
 03-JAN-20  3
 04-JAN-20  4
 05-JAN-20  5
 06-JAN-20  0
 07-JAN-20  6
 08-JAN-20  7
 09-JAN-20  8
 10-JAN-20  9

 Expected result
 07-JAN-20  6
 08-JAN-20  7
 09-JAN-20  8
 10-JAN-20  9


Another option (requires two table scans, though) would be
 <snip>
 23    SELECT *
 24      FROM PERIODS
 25     WHERE period > (SELECT period
 26                       FROM periods
 27                      WHERE VALUE = 0)
 28  ORDER BY VALUE;

PERIOD          VALUE
---------- ----------
2020-01-07          6
2020-01-08          7
2020-01-09          8
2020-01-10          9

SQL>


From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   PERIODS
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY period
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( non_zero+ $ )
         DEFINE non_zero AS value != 0
       )

and, in earlier versions, you can use:
SELECT period, value
FROM   (
  SELECT period, value,
         COUNT(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (
           ORDER BY period ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         ) AS num_zero
  FROM   periods
)
WHERE  num_zero = 0

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE PERIODS (period, value) AS 
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-02', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-04', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-05', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-06', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-07', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-08', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-09', 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE '2020-01-10', 9 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



PERIOD
VALUE




2020-01-07 00:00:00
6


2020-01-08 00:00:00
7


2020-01-09 00:00:00
8


2020-01-10 00:00:00
9



fiddle

If your database supports, you can use a conditional_true_event Window Function to achieve this as following.
SQL Query
select *
from periods
qualify conditional_true_event(observation = 0) over (order by period asc) = 1

Query Output



period
value




2020-01-06
0


2020-01-07
6


2020-01-08
7


2020-01-09
8


2020-01-10
9



More information: https://qosf.com/using-conditional_true_event-to-get-a-subset-of-data-from-timeseries-data-based-on-an-event.html
